# Link and tree field to current site context

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

In multiple sites, is it possible to make the link and tree field to map to current website context in Sitecore ?

Comment: Your should have different template and set different datasource for template fields.

Comment: What kind of link are you using? General Link, Droplink,Internal Link, General Link with Search, Grouped Droplink ?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber : i am using "General Link"  and "tree" field

Comment: Don't use tree use Tree List, tree it's a deprecated field

Comment: @SitecoreClimber : "Tree list" gives you option to select more than one item, and i want the same view of "tree" to select only one item.

Answer (score 3):

In your case you need to use relative source for your fields. 
For the tree list you can use:

```
datasource=query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='Site']/*
```

Comment: The `TreeList` does not support query datasources. See this for information on that: http://getfishtank.ca/blog/treelist-data-source-hidden-functionality. This would work on a `DropLink` field tho

Comment: I tried this before it did not work with me with both fields "tree" and "General Link"

Comment: @RichardSeal That's not quite true either, the Treelist field *does* support queries since Sitecore 7.2 :p https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/01/06/specifying-query-and-parameters-for-sitecore-treelist-field-source/

Comment: @jammykam was faster then me to send his blog post